# PHP preg_replace unexpected Output in case of matching special Character '$'

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, special-characters

I got an Issue in a PHP Script, in case of this function for regular expression matching and replacing.
I've tested my regular Expression on www.regex101.com and got always expected results, but not in PHP.

I use this Pattern inside the Function:

```
$matchedName = preg_replace("/^(\$|\(.+\))( ?)/", "", $name);
```

To match Character '$' or any Expression in Brackets at the Begin and delete this. Any Input with Brackets works well.

```
$name = "$ blah";
$matchedName = preg_replace("/^(\$|\(.+\))( ?)/", "", $name);
var_dump($matchedName);

Output:
string(8) "$ blah"
```

Now, got i missunderstood something? Or got this Function really an Issue in Case of the '$' Character?

Thanks for any Replies

Comment: So you want to delete the space in the string?

Comment: What's the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$re = "/^(\\$|\\(.+\\))( ?)/im";
$str = "\$ blah";
$subst = "";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Try this.This is working.

Comment: I did. This is correct, but provides no explanation of the problem.

Comment: Enclosing the regex in apostrophes is better because it requires less escaping.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the `\`, so your code should be:

```
$name = "$ blah";
$regex = "/^(\\\$|\(.+\))( ?)/";
$matchedName = preg_replace($regex, "", $name);

var_dump($regex);
var_dump($matchedName);
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/jxWJyg)

The problem is that you are in double quotes (`"..."`), so the PHP interpreter interprets the first `\` as merely escaping the `$` within the string, not as a literal `\`. It needs to be a literal `\` for purposes of escaping a character in a regex.

Your actual regex therefore looks like this, after the processor interprets it: `/^($|\(.+\))( ?)/`. You need to escape the `$` inside double quotes *and* provide a slash in the regex context, so you add `\\`.

Note that you could avoid this by simply using single quotes (`'...'`) instead, and you would only need `\$` instead of `\\\$`:

```
$name = "$ blah";
$regex = '/^(\$|\(.+\))( ?)/';
$matchedName = preg_replace($regex, "", $name);

var_dump($regex);
var_dump($matchedName);
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/ZCahfg)

Comment: This looks like the correct explanation, however it doesn't stand. Try to `echo()` the original regex instead of using it with `preg_match()` and you'll find out that PHP doesn't interpret the dollar sign (`$`) as a variable (because it is not followed by characters that are allowed in variable names).

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood me. I'm not saying that PHP otherwise *would* interpret it as a variable. I'm saying that the first slash accomplishes nothing other than telling it the `$` is a literal character.

Comment: Oops, you're right. A closer look to the output of the `echo()` reveals the first backslash is swallowed, escaping the `$` as you were saying. I didn't pay enough attention to it when I commented earlier.